# Self-dual and anti-self-dual decomposition

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, hodge-theory

Please take a look at the following:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a four-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifold. The Hodge star operator $*$ obeys $**=Id$ acting on 2-forms. This allow us to decompose the vector space of 2-forms into eigenspaces of $*$:
>   $$\Lambda^2(M)=\Lambda^2_{+}(M)\oplus\Lambda^2_{-}(M)$$
>   where a 2-form $\omega\in\Lambda^2_{\pm}(M)$ iff $*\omega=\pm\omega$

My questions are:

1. How is this decomposition possible?
2. Why are the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The eigenvalues of any $\Bbb R$-linear involution have to be $\pm 1$. If $Tx=\lambda x$ and $T^2=Id$, then $x=T^2(x)=\lambda^2 x$ implies $\lambda=\pm 1$. (Actually this should remain true in any field with characteristic not $2$.)

The decomposition in this case is easy to work out. You have two eigenspaces $V=\{x\mid Tx=x\}$ and $W=\{x\mid Tx=-x\}$. Note that $y-Ty\in W$ for all $y\in M$, and $y+Ty\in V$ for all $y$. Thus $y=\frac12((y-Ty) + (y+Ty))\in W+V$ for arbitrary $y$. Finally it's easy to check that $W\cap V=\{0\}$. Thus $W\oplus V$ is a direct sum.

Comment: You have explain very well, thanks a lot!

Comment: @rschwieb It should be $y + Ty \in V$ instead of just $Ty$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Oh, hm, that's odd. Perhaps when I wrote it back then I had the case of $T^2=T$ in mind. Thank you!